# Is there any way to Print Scrollable HTML View with Proper Margins and alignment for specific Page Size (Ex. A4 Page) in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to print Scrollable Screen which is developed in Angular using HTML and CSS where I'm able to print it but not getting perfect Output like its not separating Pages with proper Margins and the content inside is sticking to the borders of the page and not getting the expected result.
Expected Result is to print content Inside the Template Preview (Scrollable Area) with proper Margins and properly Separated for multiple pages for specific page Size (A4).

Given Below Link is some Solution I found Similar with my Issue but I'm unable to get proper Output after its Implementation in My Project.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-split-html-page-in-a4-size-in-angular-9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Please Help me out to get any proper Solution.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you have tried.  Include the CSS as well since that also seems to be in play here.